# ¿Existe un equivalente a "{0} {1}..." / "{variable} ..." en javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

No estoy muy seguro si lo he visto antes, creo que en **CoffeScript**. Una forma de escribri string utilizando variables o argumentos al estilo **c#** por ejemplo.

```
var nombre = "Jesse";
var text1 = $"Hola, me llamo {nombre}";
var text2 = string.Format("Hola, me llamo {0}", nombre);
```

Si es posible en **JavaScript** me gustaria saver de que forma puedo hacerlo. He estado buscando en internert por un largo tiempo y no he encontrado nada reslacionado.

El codigo actual es el siguiente

```
function getDimensions(item)
{
    return "{item.css('padding-left')} {item.css('padding-top')} {item.css('padding-right')} {item.css('padding-bottom')}";
}
// output: {item.css('padding-left')} {item.css('padding-top')} {item.css('padding-right')} {item.css('padding-bottom')}
```

El objectivo es optener `'10,5,30,0'` el paddin de un elemento. estoy utilizando jQuery.

Comment: Estás utilizando Node en el back? o quieres imprimir eso en el front?

Comment: En CofeeScript es `"Hola, me llamo #{nombre}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se les conoce como **[Plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)** o en inglés *template strings*.

Remplazas los delimitadores de cadena normales por un símbolo que en inglés se llama backtick `` ` ``.

Pueden ser peligrosos porque se adaptan a lo que pongas agregando automáticamente saltos de línea si el contenido los tiene implícitamente, es decir, aunque no pongas `\n`.

```js
console.log(`línea 1 de la cadena de texto 
línea 2 de la cadena de texto`);
```

Para escapar el texto ejecutable lo pones dentro de las llaves del constructo `${}`.

por ejemplo

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Quince es ${a + b} y\nno ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

A esta forma se le conoce como interpolación.

Javascript no soporta nativamente el formateo tradicional, si necesitas usarlo, puedes usar alguna librería como [sprintf](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) para evitar programar tu mismo el código.

Answer (score 1):

Como te menciona Ruslan López. Una posible forma de hacerlo es utilizando **``** para delimitar las cadenas. De la siguiente forma:

```js
var a = "hola";
var b = "mundo";
console.log(`Ahora ... un saludo ${a} ${b}`);
```

Otra forma es que implementes tu propia función que te permita hacer eso, dependiendo de lo que necesites resolver:

```js
function parse(str) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
        i = 0;

    return str.replace(/%s/g, () => args[i++]);
}

var nombre = "mundo";
s = parse('hola %s', nombre);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Ese no es mi nombre señor Park :P

Comment: Perdoneme Señor Ruslan López, mi debilidad visual en ocasiones mi limita jajaja

Comment: No hay fijón bro. yo ando en las mismas, y no me pesa, solo que le he invertido mucho tiempo del posicionamiento de mi nombre en google y todo suma.